# LastCounter and LastHelp values of the performance registry are corrupted and need to be updated

Tags: windows-server-2008, backupexec

I'm on a x64 Server 2008 system.  I'm seeing these 2 error messages in my event log periodically:

WARNING: 
  The LastCounter and LastHelp values of the performance registry are corrupted and need to be updated. The first and second DWORDs in the Data Section contain the original LastCounter and LastHelp values, respectively, while the third and fourth DWORDs in the Data Section contain the updated new values.

ERROR:
  The performance counter name string value in the registry is not formatted correctly. The malformed string is 17894. The first DWORD in the Data section contains the index value to the malformed string while the second and third DWORDs in the Data section contain the last valid index values.

Both of these have source as LoadPerf, and are followed by an information message from LoadPerf:
  Performance counters for the Backup Exec (Backup Exec) service were loaded successfully. The Record Data in the data section contains the new index values assigned to this service.

As I said before, these 3 messages repeat periodically.

[KB 300956](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956) leads me to believe that the performance counter library needs to be rebuilt. The instructions supposedly include 2008, but I don't have an i386 directory on my install CD, and can't find the perfc009.da_ or perfh009.da_ files anywhere on the cd.

So i guess I'm looking for 2 things.  1) simply where I can find those files for 2008 x64, and even better 2) if someone has dealt with these errors on server 2008 and can give me any advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I've done it on Win 2008 as yet, but have certainly rebuilt a number of perf counter library's on Win 2003.

The snippet of information you're missing is in fact buried in the KB article you posted, I'm assuming this still applies to Win 2008 as the KB lists it as applicable to Win 2008:

> To rebuild all Performance counters
>   including extensible and third-party
>   counters in Windows Server 2003, type
>   the following commands at a command
>   prompt. Press ENTER after each
>   command.  cd\windows\system32 lodctr
>   /R Note /R is uppercase. You must have
>   administrative rights on the computer
>   to successfully perform this command.
>
> Windows Server 2003 rebuilds all the
>   counters because it reads all the .ini
>   files in the C:\Windows\inf\009 folder
>   for the English operating system.

For your issue, it's actually a known problem with Backup Exec.

[Application event 2006 and 3001 (LoadPerf) are recorded during hotfix installation on Windows 2008](http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/317746.htm)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever seen this once, and a reboot actually corrected it. Have you tried rebooting the server?